# The sum of array elements using pointer in C

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[] = { 5, 5, 8, 34, 12, 2 };
    int *p;
  
    int i = 0, c = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(p = &a[i]; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++) {  
        sum += *p;
    }
    printf("the sum is %d\n", sum);
}
```

I tried to find the sum of array elements using pointer, but the result is not correct. The value of `i` does seem to increment, but it is not observed in the expression `a[i]`. I want to know why incrementing `i` is not having an effect on indexing the array `a`.

Comment: You never increment `p`.

Comment: i increment i ,and p=&a[i];so p must to be point to the next element !

Comment: C isn't Excel.  `p` doesn't change when `&a[i]` changes unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: okey  ,but whyy?

Comment: My fix would be to try to change the increment to `p=&a[++i]`, but I _feel_ like that isn't a good approach.

Comment: @anas You initialize the value as the address of the first element, and incrementing a variable you used in that calculation doesn't update that variable. It's like saying `a = 3; b = 2*i; i++`, that wouldn't change b from 6 to 8.

Comment: The correct way to write this is to get rid of the pointer `p` in the first place and use `a[i]` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this for loop

```
  for(p=&a[i];i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);i++){  
    sum+= *p;
  }
```

the pointer `p` always points to the first element of the array because the pointer is initialized only once `p=&a[i]`  when `i` is equal to `0` and is not being changed within the for loop.

If you want to use a pointer to access elements of the array in the for loop then the variable `i` is redundant. Instead write

```
  int a[] = { 5, 5, 8, 34, 12, 2 };
  const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
 
  int sum = 0;

  for ( const int *p = a; p != a + N; ++p ){  
      sum += *p;
  }
  printf( "the sum is %d\n",sum );
```

Pay attention to that in this declaration within the for statement

```
const int *p = a;
```

the array designator `a` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. So it is enough to write as shown above instead of

```
const int *p = &a[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use pointers, then you need to get rid of the residue from your earlier code which used the subscript operator.

Here `p` points at `&a[0]` (`a` alone decays into an `int*` here so no need to write out `&a[0]`) and `end` points at one element beyond the last element. The iteration should therefore stop when `p == end`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[] = {5, 5, 8, 34, 12, 2};

    int sum = 0;

    for (int *p = a, *end = a + sizeof a / sizeof *a; p != end; ++p) {
        sum += *p;
    }

    printf("the sum is %d\n", sum);
}
```